# django queryset: How I can override values in django queryset before sending the response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

I am on something where I need to override the values according to the URL parameters.

Model: Person

| Name | Alias |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | {"Alex", "Jacob" |

Alias column is the Array type

I get alias from the URL parameter like:
example.com/?alias=Alex
here alias = Alex

and my query is
queryset = Person.objects.filter(name=alias)

and finally, I have to send the response to the frontend like
<QuerySet [<Person: "Alex">]

basically here I have to remove Jacob from the Alias

**I have tried**

```
for qs in list(queryset):
    if "Alex" in qs["alias"]:
        qs["alias"] = ["Alex"]
```

it is working but I need to return response in the form of queryset object

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue

```
for qs in queryset:
    qs.alias = "Alex"
return queryset
```